# What type of function satisfies $f(x,y)=f\left(-x,\frac{1}{y}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Is there a name for functions satisfying the condition below?

> $f(x,y)=f\left(-x,\frac{1}{y}\right)$

Comment: What do you have in mind for the domain of such a function? Just $\mathbb R\times\langle0,\infty\rangle$, or something else?

Comment: what are you taking as domain and codomain? do you impose any regularity on the function?

Comment: For $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: I guess I am willing to rise up on my high horse and declare in all my authority that there is no established name for such functions.

Comment: It's even with respect to $x$ but I'm not sure what you would call the condition on $y$. An example would be $\cos(x)(y^2+\frac{1}{y^2})$ though.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that both functions

$$x\mapsto \iota_1(x):=-x,\hspace{.5cm} y\mapsto \iota_2(y):=\tfrac{1}{y},$$

are [involutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_%28mathematics%29):

$$\iota_1(\iota_1(x))=-(-x)=x,\hspace{.5cm} \iota_2(\iota_2(y))=\tfrac{1}{\left(\tfrac{1}{y}\right)}=y.$$

Now whenever you have an operation $\iota$ with $\iota(\iota(x))=x$, which for $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ are in fact all functions which mirrored with respect to the $45°$ axis, then for *any* function $f$, the function $$\hat{f}(x):=f(x)+f(\iota(x)),$$ with $+$ commutative, fulfills $$\hat{f}(\iota(x))=f(\iota(x))+f(\iota(\iota(x)))=f(\iota(x))+f(x)=f(x)+f(\iota(x))=\hat{f}(x)$$

Actually, via the identity

$$f(x)=\tfrac{1}{2}\left(f(x)+f(\iota(x))\right)+\tfrac{1}{2}\left(f(x)-f(\iota(x))\right),$$

all functions have a part which fullfills the relation, except the ones which fulfill the anti-relation $f(\iota(x))=-f(x)$ for which that part is zero. The above works for any number of arguments.

Take for example $f(x,y):=x\ \text e^y$, which can be split into $$f(x)=\tfrac{1}{2}\left(x\ \text e^y+(-x)\ \text e^\frac{1}{y}\right)+\tfrac{1}{2}\left(x\ \text e^y-(-x)\ \text e^\frac{1}{y}\right).$$
The first part (which we would write as the function $\propto x\left(\text e^y-\text e^\frac{1}{y}\right)$) clearly does the trick, as $x\mapsto -x$ amonts to flipping the two exponentials, which which are also flip.

The function $\cos(x)\left(y^2+\tfrac{1}{y}\right)$ is the first part of $2\cos(x)y^2$. Remark: "It's even with respect to $x$" isn't properly true, as the condition on demands you to do something with $y$ too.